# Big difference in default vieworts

Tags: css, google-chrome, viewport, mozilla

I have developed a site, and i was wondering why it looks differently on all browser , e.g scaled and so on.

Using [this](http://mydevice.io/) site a found out why. On the default scale (ctrl + 0) my viewport on chrome is 1920 , but on mozilla its 1536 , thats a big difference. Is there any css trick that could make the viewport of the browsers the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about this stuff cause I'm still learning it too but you can try setting the viewport to the initial scale of 1 but other than that make sure everything you are using is compatible with all browsers and is some of your CSS uses px to do something like padding then change it to % so that it will scale correctly until it hits a "breakpoint." I don't know if any of that helps but as far as I know, you really just have to write the CSS while minding that it's not gonna be on the same viewport.